# Converting from SQL Server 2000 to 2005 for ASP.NET web App

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm moving my ASP.NET website to a new provider. Only problem is, old host support my SQL Server 2000 db. New host only supports SQL Server 2005. 
How should I go about the conversion ? 
Can I simply produce a backup of the 2000 (.bak) file at the old host, and restore that file into SQL Server 2005 at the new host ?
Or is there more to it ??

Note that I don't own a copy of SQL Server 2005 at home... and I'm trying to avoid having to do so.

Thanks,
Bazza

Comment: You can download SQL Server 2005 Express which is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate Deployment scripts using "**[Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en)**" for your Sql200 database and select target dataabse type as "sql2005". It should work flawlessly as we have experienced the same in past.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick response..
Is the "Database Publishing Wizard"  part of the SQL Server Enterprise Manager for 2000 ? I couldn't see that wizard anywhere ??
Thanks

Comment: Sorry.. just saw the link... i've downloaded the publisher. thanks again.

Comment: Just tried that.. it seems to have worked really well. thanks again!

Comment: I don't seem to get a vote ?? Too new as a user on this site perhaps ?

Comment: you will find a check-mark option below the vote-count of my answer. You shall click on it to mark my answer as accepted answer by you. This will help others to easily find the right workable solution for the query he might have similar to your question - and of course it will gain me some reputation on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Simple restoring of backup is enough. It workes fine for me.

Comment: I've never had a problem restoring 2000 backups onto 2005 either.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Data Transformation Services (DTS)? This SQL Server 2000 feature can't be migrated right away into SQL Server 2005. You'll have to migrate your DTS-packages to SQL Server Integration Services.

Running the [SQL Server 2005 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1470e86b-7e05-4322-a677-95ab44f12d75&displaylang=en) helps identifying this issue.

Comment: Not strictly true. The "backward compatibility" components can be installed to allow SQL 2005 to run DTS packages.